# SQL - counting different items in specific column in each day

Tags: sql

```
Date                Time        Method          User                   App
2013/5/24        19:39:33        PUT        advantage_user        adv_cat_arch
2013/5/24        19:36:04        SETACL        advantage_user        adv_cat_arch
2013/5/24        19:36:11        PUT        advantage_user        adv_cat_arch
2013/5/24        19:36:12        SETACL        advantage_user        adv_cat_arch
2013/5/24        19:36:19        PUT        advantage_user        adv_cat_arch
2013/5/24        19:36:19        SETACL        advantage_user        adv_cat_arch
2013/5/24        19:36:27        PUT        advantage_user        adv_cat_arch
```

I wanna count each Methods in each day, for example,

```
Date        Method(PUT)    Method(SETACL)  Method(Get)
2013/5/24       5                2             3
2013/5/25       2                1             5
```

This is my sql query:

```
SELECT Fas_ops_metrics_test4_jun.Date as Date, 
       Fas_ops_metrics_test4_jun.Method as Method
FROM Fas_ops_metrics_test4_jun
GROUP BY Fas_ops_metrics_test4_jun.Method
ORDER BY Fas_ops_metrics_test4_jun.Method;
```

anyone can help me ?  thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can do this with `COUNT` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT Date, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Method = 'PUT' THEN 1 END) 'Method(PUT)',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Method = 'SETACL' THEN 1 END) 'Method(SETACL)',
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Method = 'GET' THEN 1 END) 'Method(GET)'
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Date
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/804ac/1) (with your sample data)

---

Edit, given that you're using MS Access, use `IIF` instead of `CASE` and perhaps easier with `SUM`:

```
SELECT Date, 
    SUM(IIF(Method = 'PUT', 1, 0)) as 'Method(PUT)',
    SUM(IIF(Method = 'SETACL', 1, 0)) as 'Method(SETACL)',
    SUM(IIF(Method = 'GET', 1, 0)) as 'Method(GET)'
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Hi sgeddes, Thank you for helping , but when I run this query, database shows "syntax error : count......(PUT) without operand...."

Comment: @user2460718 -- can you be more specific?  Perhaps update the Fiddle with your error?  What database are you using?

Comment: @user2460718 -- MS Access may not support the `CASE` statement.  It should support the `IIF` statement though which works similarly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count (method) , method
from yourTable 
Where Date = '2013/5/24'
group by method
```

That will give you two columns, a count of each method and the method.